# Why is sampling distribution of means's standard deviation sd/sqrt(n)?

Tags: statistics, means, sampling, sampling-theory

I'm so used to seeing standard deviations being the sqrt of the entire formula so it's weird to me to see a SD that is defined as sd/sqrt(n). Can someone explain why?

Comment: https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/sigma-sqrt-n-used/

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskStatistics/comments/66a0fr/whats_the_reasoning_for_dividing_be_sqrtn_when/

Answer (score 1):

It is the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) of the mean which is $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$

If a sample of $n$ i.i.d. random variables each have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

- then their sum has mean $n\mu$ and variance $n\sigma^2$ since they are independent
- so their mean has mean $\dfrac{n \mu}{n}=\mu$ and variance $\dfrac{n\sigma^2}{n^2}=\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}$ since you are dividing by a constant
- leading to their mean having standard deviation $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}} = \dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ by taking the square root of the variance